# Is Iterative Deepening Search supposed to be that slow?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, c++11, recursion

My Data Structure:

```
class Cell
{
public:
    struct CellLink 
    {
        Cell *cell;
        int weight;
    };
public:
    int row;
    int column;
    vector<CellLink> neighbors;
    State state;
    int totalCost = 0;
};
```

The primary function:

```
    void AI::IterativeDeepeningSearch(Cell* cell)
        {
            Cell* temp;
            int bound = 0;


        while (true)
        {
            naturalFailure = false;
            temp = IDShelper(cell, bound);

            if (IsExit(temp))
            {
                break;
            }
            bound++;
        }   
    }
```

The Helper:

```
Cell* AI::IDShelper(Cell* cell, int bound)
{
    Cell* temp = cell;

    SetEnvironment(cell, State::visited);
    PrintEnvironment();

    if (bound > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cell->neighbors.size(); i++)
        {
            temp = IDShelper(cell->neighbors[i].cell, bound - 1);
            if (IsExit(temp))
            {
                naturalFailure = true;
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (IsExit(cell))
    {
        return cell;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I have made an Iterative Deepening Search for a maze. The problem is that it is taking literally hours to complete the search on a 21x21 maze while other algorithms take a couple of seconds.

I know that IDS is supposed to be slow but is it supposed to be *that* slow?

Comment: Other algorithms like? The closest comparison is BFS, but the results will still be largely dependent on where the target node is (but if BFS takes seconds and DFS ID takes hours, there's likely something wrong).

Comment: @Dukeling I have implemented BFS and UFC and they just need around 3-4 seconds

Comment: Seems unlikely it should be several orders of magnitude slower.  I'd check your recursion to make sure you're not accidentally revisiting the same things over and over.  For example, self->neighbor->neighbor coming back to self..

Comment: @JoeZ That seems to be *exactly* what's happening.

Comment: Joe might be right, shouldn't you have a check for whether a cell is visited before recursing or at the start of your recursive function?

Comment: @JoeZ I was pretty sure I minimized that possibility by marking the cells as visited but maybe there is something wrong with my pointers

Comment: oh now I see what you mean, I never checked before calling the helper on a neighbor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can see why this is slow.

In your helper, you're visiting the neighbors like so:

```
if (bound > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cell->neighbors.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = IDShelper(cell->neighbors[i].cell, bound - 1);
        if (IsExit(temp))
        {
            naturalFailure = true;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

but you're never using past results. You mark something as visited, but never check whether it is already visited.

Comment: I think that's what's wrong. Let me get back to you in a bit after checking it

Comment: That actually did not work, it sent me through an infinite loop. But maybe after each level of searching I need to clean the states of each cell. I'll try that

Comment: @Powerbyte Yeah, definitely clear the states after each level.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that and I'll get back to you

Comment: I have to leave soon, so if I can't help you fully before then, I'll have to let people like Dukeling and JoeZ pick up where I left off.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: I managed to fix it with the answer you provided me with but there seems to be some other minor problems with my algorithm but nothing too major. Thanks again.